ENOSPC Error When Saving Figures with Matplotlib: No Space Left on Device
I'm encountering an ENOSPC (No space left on device) error in my Python script while trying to save figures generated by Matplotlib. The error only occurs when executing the plt.savefig(f'outputs/{filename}_xyz.png', dpi=400) line; when I comment it out, the script runs without issues and prints output image.
Error:
File Save Error for Untitled.ipynb
Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb [Errno 28] No space left on device
import pandas as pd
quantaq_file = 'MOD8765.csv'
quantaq = pd.read_csv(quantaq_file)
quantaq.head(2)

quantaq['timestamp_local'] = pd.to_datetime(quantaq['timestamp_local'])

desired_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

quantaq['timestamp_local'] = quantaq['timestamp_local'].dt.strftime(desired_format)

print(quantaq.head(2))
quantaq = quantaq.rename(columns={'timestamp_local':"Time",'pm25':"pm25_quantaq"})
quantaq['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(quantaq['Time'])
quantaq = quantaq[["Time","pm25_quantaq"]]
quantaq.set_index("Time", inplace=True)
quantaq = quantaq.resample("h").mean()
#quantaq = quantaq[quantaq.index >'2024-04-01 00:00:00']
quantaq

import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = 'TARA_UNDP' 

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if file.endswith('xlsx'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        print(f"Processing file: {file_path}")

        filename = os.path.basename(file_path).split(".")[0]
        print(f"Filename: {filename}")

        excel_data = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, header=None)
        
        for sheet_name, sheet_df in excel_data.items():
            print(f"Processing sheet: {sheet_name}")
            try:
                df = sheet_df.copy()
                df = df.iloc[:, :4] 
                df.columns = ['Date', 'ID', 'pm25_undp', 'pm10_undp']
                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M', errors='coerce')
    
                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M')
                df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
                print(df.head(), len(df))
    
                df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                df = df[["Date", "pm25_undp"]]
                df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    
                df = df.resample("h").mean()
                print("Resampled DataFrame:")
                print(df)
    
                merge = pd.merge(quantaq, df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
                merge = merge.dropna()
           
                print("Merged DataFrame:")
                print(merge)
                import pandas as pd
                import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                import matplotlib.dates as mdates
                
                
                
                df1 = merge
                
                plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
                
                plt.plot(df1.index, df1['pm25_undp'], label='PM2.5_UNDP')
                plt.plot(df1.index, df1['pm25_quantaq'], label='pm25_quantaq')
                
                plt.title(f'PM2.5 Measurements Over Time: {filename}:{sheet_name}')
                plt.xlabel('Time')
                plt.ylabel('PM2.5 Values (µg/m³)')
                plt.legend()
                plt.xticks(rotation=45)  
                
                r_values = {
                    # 'PM2.5_UNDP': df1['pm25_undp'].corr(df1['pm25_quantaq']),
                    'pm25_quantaq': df1['pm25_quantaq'].corr(df1['pm25_undp'])
                }
                textstr = f'{sheet_name}:PM2.5_UNDP Correlation with:-\n' + '\n'.join([f'- {sensor}: {r_value:.4f}' for sensor, r_value in r_values.items()])
                props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', alpha=0.9)
                
                plt.text(0.23, 0.97, textstr, transform=plt.gca().transAxes, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
                
                plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
                plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))  
                
                plt.xticks(rotation=45)
                
                plt.tight_layout()
                plt.grid(True)
                
                plt.savefig(f'outputs/{filename}_{sheet_name}_undp_iitd.png', dpi=400)
                plt.show()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing sheet {filename}:{sheet_name}: {e}")
                continue  

What could be causing the ENOSPC error specifically when saving figures with plt.savefig()?
I didn't try anything, as I'm new to this error. I'm expecting to save figure.

The device in question is likely your disk, and the error message means that your disk is full, or so full that Matplotlib cannot save the figure because on disk you have not enough space available.


your disk is full, almost full: free some space on disk



your disk has, let's say, 3 GB available, so Matplotlib is likely trying to save a file larger than 3 GB, and that is PRETTY UNUSUSAL.


If your problem is no. 2 above, we cannot help until you show us your code.

@JohanC, my plot doesn't have huge number of ticks, also the plot appears in console when I don't save it.

@gboffi, I have enough space of 500GB, also when I tried to run and save it through Google Colab then it worked and saved, its size was 46MB only.

Rohan, if you still need our help you must post your code, or even better a simplified version of your code that still  shows the same problem

@gboffi, I have given the code, please have a look.
